# Stop Application from listening to a particular port

Tags: networking, rhel, oracle-linux, port

### Background

We would like to configure a Linux machine so that it doesn't automatically listen to a port; whether a default port or not. We are using **Oracle Linux** and **RHEL**.

### Issue

How can we prevent our machine from listening to, or responding to, a port automatically?

Comment: you don't have access to application to stop it? or change in its configuration? you can block in firewall if you have or use iptables rules to drop the traffic on that port. what Linux distribution are you using? would you please [edit] your question and clarify your question?

Comment: Actually this is regarding the project am working on..My mentor has given me a task to figure out..We want something like a particular linux machine should not listen to a port.. whether it's default port or not.. we are currently using Linux OL and RHEL machines..How can we achieve it ? Any linux commands that you can suggest

Comment: Honestly I don't know why people are voting to close this question as unclear.  It seems pretty obviously clear to me.  There's a reasonably high level [answer on ask.ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024399/block-process-from-using-port) for a pretty much identical question.  Even though you're using RHEL not ubuntu, it should still be meaningful.  That is you have the options of using iptables to block the port completely, or apparmor to prevent one specific app using that port while letting others use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you are trying to do so if this isn't what you are after add some more details and we'll try to help further.

Since linux doesn't automatically listen to ports you don't really have to do anything to "not listen on a port" the default position is not listening. If no service is started to listen on a port nothing will happen. Packets delivered on that port will just be dropped since no service is assigned to process them.

On the other hand if you want to say, prevent a service from listening on the port you can block the traffic before it gets to the service. One way would be with `iptables`. For example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j DROP
```

This says when traffic arrives at this computer destined for port 80, drop that traffic. Here, even if you had a webserver listening on port 80 it would not see the traffic.

It would be useful to know your exact use case as this solution may not be what you are looking for and when it comes to networking there is almost always a way around what you are trying to block.